Every simple module is isomorphic to a minimal left ideal
Let $A$ be a simple Artinian algebra. I want to prove every simple $A$-module is isomorphic to a minimal left ideal $M$ of $A$.
I do it as follows:
$MA=\sum_aMa$ is a nonzero ideal, so $MA=A$. The sum $\sum_aMa$ is finite due to the fact that $A$ is unital. $Ma \cong M$ or $Ma \cong \{0\}$ by Schur's lemma. Consequently, ${}_AA\cong M^l$ for some $l$.
Suppose $N$ is a simple $A$-module. There exists $n \in N$ such that $\phi_n:A \to N$ via $a \mapsto an$ is a nonzero map. By the simplicity of $N$, $\operatorname{im}(\phi_n)=N$, so $N \cong {}_AA/\ker(\phi_n) \cong M^{l-i} $ for some $1<i<l$. Since $N$ is simple, then $N \cong M$.
I feel my proof involves redundant parts. It seems I prove Wedderbur-Artin theorem twice. Is there a more straightforward proof?

It feels far more straightforward to just use basic isomorphism theorems, as in a solution I put on this duplicate post (since that seemed like a better place to answer.) Maybe the deal is what you're calling the AW theorem is something else from what I expect (a structural result in terms of matrix rings.)

Now I see. I did not think that every simple left module over an unital ring is isomorphic to the quotient ring by a maximal left ideal. Considering this, these two posts become more similar but not fully. I consider $A$ to be simple, so all simple modules and all left minimal ideals are isomorphic to one another. That is there is a left ideal $M$,  that every simple module is isomorphic to $M$.

AW or WA theorem?  I consider this theorem for simple Artinian algebras and semisimple algebras. The Artinian simple version is as follows: ${}_AA \cong M^l$ as modules and $A \cong Mat_l(End_A(M)^{op})$ as algebras.

I think the name ordering appears differently in different places...

The ideas presented can be shortened to a quicker proof.
You've noted that $MA = A$. This tells you that $MN = N$. In particular, there exists $n \in N$ such that $Mn \neq 0$.
Now, you can define $\phi_{n}$ as a map $M \to N$.
